# How to properly read integer from file in Java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have read previous posts and tryed to integrate code in to my project. 
I am  trying to read integers from my txt file. 
I am using this method:

```
 static Object[] readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    List<Integer> tall = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        tall.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    return tall.toArray();
}
```

I don't know the size of data, so i am using List
in main calling method:

```
Object [] arr = readFile("C:\\02.txt");
System.out.println(arr.length);
```

I am getting that the array size is 0; 
The integers i am trying to read from the file is binary Sequence. (1010101010...)
I thought that the problem is connected with scanner maybe he thinks that it is not the integer.

Comment: I've never had much love for Scanner, my personal approach would be to read it as a text file (if numbers are on lines), and parse it using Integer.parseInt()

Comment: well, i will go your suggestion and will read from file just like text, beside when i am seperating bits with spaces my code works.)

Comment: If the input file is not super large, you could just load it all into a string and parse it with regex. It's pretty fast and efficient for smaller files (several kilobytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BufferReader` instead :

```
String line = "";
List<Integer> tall = new ArrayList<Integer>();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
        tall.add(Integer.parseInt(line, 2));
    }
    br.close();
}catch(IOException e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading data in binary form then consider using `nextInt` or `hasNextInt` with radix.

```
while (scanner.hasNextInt(2)) {
    tall.add(scanner.nextInt(2));
}
```

Otherwise you will be reading integers as decimals so values may be out of integers range like in case of

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```